# WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied using boto/python

Tags: python, boto

I want to download all the files and folders in the bucket. This is my code

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                           AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
key.get_contents_to_filename('path/to/folder')
```

error-

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 1726, in get_contents_to_filename
    os.remove(filename)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'path/to/folder'
```

Please help me overcome the problem!

Comment: try running the cmd with administrator permissions

Comment: still not working !

Comment: Just to clarify on Stack's comment, go to start, type cmd, shift-right-click cmd.exe and choose "run as administrator", navigate to your python script folder and run `python yourscript.py` or possibly `C:\Python27\python yourscript.py`.

To further add; make sure `path/to/folder` is not just a path, but contains the filename of what you are trying to access, `os.remove` can only handle files directly, thats why.

Comment: Referrenses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625062/cant-remove-a-folder-with-os-remove-windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528020/why-am-i-getting-windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied

Comment: ok that makes sense........but i want to download the zip files present in my bucket which contains multiple directories in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this exact problem. The problem is that S3 Buckets don't have directories. The file structure is flat but every key is named as if it were a path name.

So if you have

```
bucket
|
|__dir1
   |
   |_file1
   |_file2
```

You'll actually have keys

```
bucket/dir1/
bucket/dir1/file1
bucket/dir1/file2
```

For me (in a Windows OS), the `get_contents_to_filename` works for file keys (`bucket/dir1/file1`) but fails for directory keys (`bucket/dir1`), which triggers `os.remove(filename)` and ultimately the PermissionError.

Instead you can try to recursively iterate through your directory structure and *get_contents_to_filename* for file keys and *mkdir* for directory keys (these end in a slash '/').

Answer (score 4):

I Was facing the same issue with boto3. This is what I was trying-

```
s3.Object('<bucket>','<prefix>/<filename>').download_file('C:\myfolder')
```

I tried multiple things like running as an admin, giving different local paths, giving public user paths etc and nothing worked. The issue was that I was providing a **folder** path and not a **file** path. So this worked in the end-

```
s3.Object('<bucket>','<prefix>/<filename>').download_file('C:\myfolder\<filename>')
```

Comment: This actually was the solution for my 3 days long search to solve read-only access to folder..