# How to remove file after uploading it to Google Drive

Tags: python-2.7, google-api-client

I have written code in python that uploads a file to Google Drive, but after it uploads I cannot delete it from local drive, because I get error "Access Denied", but if I exit out of function then I can delete the file. So my question is how can I delete the file from inside the function?

> GDriveUpload.py

```
import os
import httplib2
import ntpath
import oauth2client
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# Copy your credentials here
_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
_CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'
_PARENT_FOLDER_ID = 'YOUR_PARENT_FOLDER_ID'
_DATA_FILE = 'datafile.dat'

# ====================================================================================

# Upload file to Google Drive
def UploadFile(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, parent_folder_id, local_file, DeleteOnExit=False):
    cred = oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials(None,client_id,client_secret,refresh_token,None,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',None)
    http = cred.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(local_file, mimetype='application/octet-stream', chunksize=5242880, resumable=True)
    body = {
        'title': (ntpath.basename(local_file)),
        'parents': [{'id': parent_folder_id}],
        'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
    request = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body)
    response = None
    while response is None:
        status, response = request.next_chunk()
        if status:
            print "Uploaded %.2f%%" % (status.progress() * 100)
    if DeleteOnExit == True:
        os.remove(local_file)

# ====================================================================================


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UploadFile(_CLIENT_ID, _CLIENT_SECRET, _REFRESH_TOKEN, _PARENT_FOLDER_ID, _DATA_FILE, DeleteOnExit=True)
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether your situation is same with this thread, is this useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11625062/7108653

Comment: no, I already read this thread and it's not useful. because there was the problem with a folder, but I have file, that I don't know where is used in my code and I cannot delete it

Comment: I'm really sorry my comment was not useful for your situation.